# Accessing file uploaded via Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to do some processing on a file uploaded via POST to my tastypie API. Here are my models and my resources.

**Resource**

```
class TagResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    track = fields.FileField(attribute="track", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'tag'
        authorization = Authorization()
        #object_class = Tag
        always_return_data = True

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle = super(TagResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
        bundle.obj = Tag(track=bundle.data.get('track'))
        bundle.obj.save()
        #the following line is the processing intended.
        result = recognize(bundle.obj.track)
        bundle.data['tag'] = result
        return bundle
```

**Models**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    track = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.UPLOAD_DIR, max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.track.url
```

It seems the new object is created but the uploaded file never gets saved. I deduced that since making a get request to the api shows the newly created Tag object but with track as null.

```
15:Object
id:101
resource_uri:""
track:null
```

What i'm I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Seems like I was not posting correctly using CURL. I now use this to upload the file:

```
curl -F "track=@/path/to/file.mp3" http://1**.**.***.**:8000/api/tag/
```

The '@' before the path was missing before. Adding that fixed it.